# Warning: Function definition inside an Objective-C object is deprecated

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, objective-c-category

After upgrading to Xcode 6.3, I'm now getting this warning:

```
Warning: Function definition inside an Objective-C object is deprecated
```

The warning is appearing in a category on NSString, where I've defined a `UIKIT_STATIC_INLINE` method.

Here's the offending code:

```
// NSString+Helpers.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (Helpers)

+ (BOOL)exampleCategoryMethod;

UIKIT_STATIC_INLINE NSString *NSStringFromCLLocationCoordinate2D(CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 6):

I simply had to move my static inline function definition outside of my `@interface`.

Here's the modified code:

```
// NSString+Helpers.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

UIKIT_STATIC_INLINE NSString *NSStringFromCLLocationCoordinate2D(CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
}

@interface NSString (Helpers)

+ (BOOL)exampleCategoryMethod;

@end
```

Comment: In fact, this way is also valid to c++ in Object-C.